# What does it mean to expand a generating function?

Tags: generating-functions

I'm reading generatingfunctionology, and the author came up with this generating function:

$$
A(x) = \frac{x}{(1-x)(1-2x)} = x\{\frac{2}{1-2x} - \frac{1}{1-x}\}
$$

Then he expands it. Which I thought was supposed to be:

$$
\sum_{n \ge 0} (x\{\frac{2}{1-2x} - \frac{1}{1-x}\})^n
$$

But judging from the result:

$$
\{2x + 2^2x^2 + 2^3x^3 + ...\} - \{x + x^2 + x^3 + ...\}
$$

He seems to be doing:

$$
\sum_{n \ge 0} (x\frac{2}{1-2x})^n - \sum_{n \ge 0} (x\frac{1}{1-x})^n
$$
Which means I completely misunderstand the idea behind this process. So why is *this* the expansion?

Comment: This is not a step of finding a generating function for $A$ (which is presented as a function of real numbers, not a sequence anyway). It's writing a sum which is exactly equal to $A(x)$ when the sum converges.

Comment: Aaah.. That's what I didn't get! The author didn't even mention anything about geometric series, so this must've been very obvious.. for others :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The power series for $\frac{1}{1-x}$ (e.g., see [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)) is
$$\frac{1}{1-x} = 1 + x + x^2 + \cdots.$$
Similarly
$$\frac{1}{1-2x} = 1 + (2x) + (2x)^2 + \cdots.$$

Comment: And the point of using partial fractions on $A(x)$ is to get the function into a form in which this can be used. If there were higher powers in the denominator eg terms like  $\frac {1}{(1-x)^{2}}$ related elementary results would come into play. [note mainly for OPs benefit]

Comment: Combined with what @aschepler left as a comment, I now have a full picture. Thanks everyone!